# Double Integral $\int_1^4\int_0^{\ln x}(4y−e^y)^2\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x$ over a region or fubini's theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have had trouble with the following double integral, and it has been suggested to me to change the order of integration
$$\int_1^4\int_0^{\ln x}(4y−e^y)^2dydx$$
When I have tried to integrate this as it is, I get to:
$$\int_1^4 \frac{16 (\ln(x))^3}{3} - 8x\ln(x) + 3x +\frac{x^2}{2} \mathrm{d}x$$
However, I haven't been able to correctly calculate the result of that integral, so I am interested in changing the order of integration to yield a simpler integral, but I am unsure how to do so.

Comment: Hi, I tried to format your second integral. Can you confirm that this is what you meant?

Comment: Yes that is what I eant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the order of integration, it usually helps to plot the region that you're integrating over. Note that $x$ is free to range over $1$ to $4$, and the bounds of $y$ change with respect to $x$, going from $0$ (the $x$-axis) to $\ln(x)$ (the curve $y = \ln(x)$). So, in total, we're looking at the region under the graph $y = \ln(x)$, between $0$ and $1$. **Make sure you draw a picture** otherwise the explanation can get confusing.

Now, let's change the order of integration. Instead of first letting $x$ range freely over its possible values of $1$ to $4$, instead let's look at the total range of values that $y$ can range over. Looking at the picture you've hopefully drawn, it should be clear that it ranges between $0$ and $\ln(4)$.

Now, take an arbitrary $y$ in this range, draw a horizontal line through it, and look at the points it intersects the region. Which values of $x$ does it take? The lower bound should be at the curve $y = \ln(x)$ and the upper bound should be $4$. So, the lower bound will be $x = e^y$ and the upper bound is $4$. Thus, our reversed integration becomes:
$$\int_0^{\ln(4)} \int_{e^y}^4 (4y - e^y)^2 \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$$
Computing the first integral becomes easier:
$$\int_0^{\ln(4)} [(4y - e^y)^2x]_{e^y}^4 \mathrm{d}y = \int_0^{\ln(4)} (4y - e^y)^2(4 - e^y) \mathrm{d}y.$$
The rest should be computable by expanding then integrating by parts.

Comment: @Julia97: I've had a thought. Could the integrand actually be $(4 - e^y)^2$, instead of $(4y - e^y)^2$?

Answer (score 0):

Direct way:
\begin{align}
\int_1^4\int_0^{\ln x}(4y−e^y)^2dydx
&= \int_1^4\int_0^{\ln x}(16y^2+e^{2y}−8ye^y)dydx \\
&= \int_1^4\left(\dfrac{16}{3}y^3+\dfrac12e^{2y}−8ye^y+8e^y\right)\Big|_0^{\ln x}\,dx \\
&= \int_1^4\left(\dfrac{16}{3}\ln^3x+\dfrac12x^2−8x\ln x+8x-\dfrac{17}{2}\right)\,dx \\
&= -21+\frac{512\ln^32}{3}-256\ln^22+128\ln2
\end{align}